# python boxplot strange behavior

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Sorry my questions could be a silly question. I like to draw bloxplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [ [71, 100, 100, 66, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 83, 80]]
plt.boxplot(x)
plt.show()
```

but it seems weird.

[image]

I know the boxplot should show the max, min, and the box between the quartile 1 and quartile 3 (ref [2](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/summarizing-quantitative-data/box-whisker-plots/a/box-plot-review)), for me they are, min=66, max=100, median 100, q1= 95.75, q3=100.
But it this case, the box plot also shows some points, 66, 71, 80, and 83, additionally on the plot.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/_images/boxplot_explanation.png

Comment: @BigBen That explanatory image is actually not congruent with the implementation in matplotlib.

Comment: The points at 66, 71, 80, and 83 are the "outliers", i.e. points outside the interval `[q1 - 1.5 * iqr, q3 + 1.5 * iqr]`.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen I was trying with Potly, it does not have this issue but is hard to plot. There is any for to set outliers as False in matplotlib?

Comment: `plt.boxplot(x, sym='')`